# Android phone cannot connect to internet via wireless, other devices can

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I recently installed a new cable modem.  After getting everything up & running, I can connect to the wireless router, and then to the internet, through laptops, desktops, and a Roku device, but I cannot access via my Android phone.  It connects to the router, but cannot get to the outside world.  If I turn off the wifi, then I can connect via my data plan, but I cannot connect via wifi.

Some details:

- The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3, and the Android OS is 4.1.2
- I use Comcast for cable internet.
- The (old and unchanged) wireless router is a Netgear device.  (I am not sure the model number, but I can get it if that seems pertinent.)
- The new cable modem is also Netgear.  It's model CMD31T and it is DOCSIS 3.0, while the old modem was quite old and I have no idea what it's level of throughput.
- I changed to the new modem because the old one was becoming "spotty" -- it would occasionally lose signal.  The new modem has so far been consistently on, and with strong signal... it's just that the phone cannot connect to it.

Comment: When it "connects to the router": does it show a wifi signal indicator in the notification bar (and if, with strong signal)? In *Settings→WiFi*, does it show "connected" with your AP, or something different (e.g. "obtaining IP address")? Any useful information in the logs, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, now the phone can find the signal fine after a few days.  I did NOTHING different.  However, I had taken many steps beforehand, such as updating the firmware, PRL & Profile, restarting the phone, restarting the cable & router.  None of those actions worked, however just waiting a few days seemed to resolve it.

This is not much of an "answer", but I am keeping the question & answer so that if anyone else has troubles, maybe theirs will also be resolved by "just waiting".